# Responsive Design Width Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Till **Large BreakPoint** everything works fine but as soon as I enter **Medium & Small BreakPoints**
**Cards** that I have created doesn't take much **space on the right side** of the page leaving it blank.

I Tried **col-sm-12, col-sm-6,col-md-12,col-md-6 ....** everything but nothing worked. (I am New To this stuff)

I am using bootstrap version 4.5.0

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9890999e8e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar-custom {
      background-color: black !important;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
      text-align: center !important;
      padding-top: 100px !important;
      background: url(1.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      color: whitesmoke;
    }
    
    .card {
      margin-bottom: 50px !important;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Patterns</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: aliceblue;"><i class="fas fa-binoculars  " ></i> Patterns</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Pattern</h1>
    <p class="lead"> Beef ribs spare ribs andouille picanha ham hock ham.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Do something</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Do anotherthing</button>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="laptop">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="laptop">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="laptop">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>





  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I made a test page before and it worked fine using col-md and col-sm, I don't know what is creating problem this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the cards are taking 18rem width i just override it with width:100%;

```css
.card {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9890999e8e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar-custom {
      background-color: black !important;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
      text-align: center !important;
      padding-top: 100px !important;
      background: url(1.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      color: whitesmoke;
    }
    
    .card {
      margin-bottom: 50px !important;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Patterns</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: aliceblue;"><i class="fas fa-binoculars  " ></i> Patterns</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Pattern</h1>
    <p class="lead"> Beef ribs spare ribs andouille picanha ham hock ham.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Do something</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Do anotherthing</button>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="laptop">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="laptop">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="laptop">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>





  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did this helped you?